# How do I change the value in display without making stateful Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

we know that if we need to update the data on the screen we need stateful widget also `SetState()` function,
but how do I change the data without using `setState` function also in `stateless` (we can't put setState function in stateless widget),

for example in flutter there is a demo increment project , here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

, and how we can build this project as the same using stateless?

Comment: You can use providers, that can help in creating stateless widgets, Also they reduce the repaint time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can use getx and provider without using setstate I hope my refernece will help you.
```

The Complete reference is here
[enter link description here](https://github.com/Prakash-Selvaraj-Ash/prakash.selvaraj-outlook.com/tree/master/provider_tuto)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_tuto/models/my_simple_model.dart';

class StatelessSimpleEx extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('I am a state less widget using stream'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Provider(
            create: (_) => MySimpleModel(),
            dispose: (_, MySimpleModel model) => model.dispose(),
            child: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
                MySimpleModel model = Provider.of<MySimpleModel>(ctx);
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    StreamBuilder<String>(
                        stream: model.textStream.stream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return Text(model.myText);
                        }),
                    TextField(
                      decoration:
                          InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter text to stream'),
                      onChanged: (textValue) => model.setMyText = textValue,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Click to update the color box'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        model.setIsValid = !model.isValid;
                      },
                    ),
                    StreamBuilder<bool>(
                        stream: model.boolStream.stream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                color:
                                    snapshot.data ? Colors.red : Colors.green);
                          } else {
                            return Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            );
                          }
                        })
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use state management techniques to update value without Setstate
here i have used [Getx library](https://pub.dev/packages/get) which help us to update state without setstate

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key? key,required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final RxInt _counter = 0.obs;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    _counter.value++;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Obx(
                  () => Text(
                '${_counter.value}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```